# TextBox Text Formatting From Style

Tags: wpf, styles

1. I have a MainWindow.XAML
2. TextBox is added to it
3. TextBox text binding is done
4. When I add StringFormat inside binding (in MainWindow.XAML) it works
5. When I add StringFormat inside Style, it's not working

below is the code from style and MainWindow.xaml

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4"   Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" Text="{Binding CustomerAmount,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>


<Style  x:Key="TextBoxStyle"   TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" >
        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},StringFormat='#,###,###,##0.00;(#,###,###,##0.00)'}"></Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you've basically applied **two** `Text` binding's now, one in MainWindow and one in `Style`.

The `Text` property set in `MainWindow.xaml` on the control has precedence over the one you're setting in `Style`, so the `StringFormat` you set via `Style` is actually never applied cos that entire `Style.Setter` is ignored.

A very rough way to make this work and prove the above statement is try switching your xaml to the following,

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4"   Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" Tag="{Binding CustomerAmount,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
```

and Style:

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle"
        TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
  <Setter Property="Text"
          Value="{Binding Tag,
                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                          StringFormat='#,###,###,##0.00;(#,###,###,##0.00)',
                          Mode=TwoWay,
                          UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</Style>
```

This will work cos you now have `Tag` binding in MainWindow and `Text` in `Style`. You can switch to a custom Attached property or DP to get the same behavior

Comment: Hi Thanks for the inputs. I also tried using Converter in Style before posting this question. Now I got the reason why it was not happening.